# How to get value from Ok(object value) using HttpPost method

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm calling login method:

```
var result = $"{Properties.Settings.Default.APIUrl}/{_route}/login".PostJsonAsync(userToLogin);
```

**From result i want to get token** var myToken = result;

This is login method in API

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserToLogin userToLogin)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userToLogin.Username);
            var result = await _signInManager
                .CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, userToLogin.Password, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = await _userManager.Users
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.NormalizedUserName == userToLogin.Username.ToUpper());

                var userToReturn = appUser;

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser).Result
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API is returning an instance of an anonymous type. So the response body should look something like this:

```
{
    "Token": "GENERATED TOKEN"
}
```

The easiest way to achieve what you need is by having a class that matches the json response. For example:

```
public class MyResponse 
{
    public string Token {get;set;}
}
```

and call the API parameterized with the type

```
var result = $"{Properties.Settings.Default.APIUrl}/{_route}/login".PostJsonAsync<MyResponse>(userToLogin);
```

What this will do is: in case your API returns with a success code (200 <= code < 300), it will deserialize the the body to that type. So you could then use result.Token

Also postJsonAsync will return you a Task so you need to await the Task in order to get MyResponse object.